# Widget not showing up on page

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I'm currently coding my own one page wordpress theme (based on underscores) and I'm trying to add a widget to a page, so this widget will show up on my homepage.

I used this page as my guide; http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes but the widget is not showing up on my homepage.

Steps I took:
1. Create a custom page template, this is the code of that:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Widget Page
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

    <?php putRevSlider("video","homepage") ?>

        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'widget-page' ); ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Seems to work fine, I can select the template and the content of my page shows up on the homepage. (See test widget, test test test)

I added the line that calls on the widget there too, as you can tell.

Then I added this to my functions.php;

```
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 */
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Widget Page',
        'id'            => 'widget-page',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

And I think that's where it's going wrong? The mentioning of a sidebar confuses me a little as this is supposed to show up on a page. The wp guide also mentions a code where it checks if the sidebar is active, but since I'm not putting it in a sidebar I'm not sure if I should use this? I tried using this piece but that also didn't work, which is why I think the problem would be in the functions.php file. The underscores framework also comes with their own piece of widget code, is this causing problems?

```
/**
 * Register widget area.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar
 */
function otto_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'otto' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'otto_widgets_init' );
```

This is a link to my page; http://kellyvuijst.nl/onepage/

Thanks in advcance!

Answer (score 0):

After some more googling I found out the easiest option to make a widget appear in a page is to make sure you can short code widgets and then just add the short code to the page. No custom templates needed.

This is the code I used in my functions.php;

```
function widget($atts) {

    global $wp_widget_factory;

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'widget_name' => FALSE
    ), $atts));

    $widget_name = wp_specialchars($widget_name);

    if (!is_a($wp_widget_factory->widgets[$widget_name], 'WP_Widget')):
        $wp_class = 'WP_Widget_'.ucwords(strtolower($class));

        if (!is_a($wp_widget_factory->widgets[$wp_class], 'WP_Widget')):
            return '<p>'.sprintf(__("%s: Widget class not found. Make sure this widget exists and the class name is correct"),'<strong>'.$class.'</strong>').'</p>';
        else:
            $class = $wp_class;
        endif;
    endif;

    ob_start();
    the_widget($widget_name, $instance, array('widget_id'=>'arbitrary-instance-'.$id,
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => ''
    ));
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode('widget','widget');
```

Which I found thanks to; https://digwp.com/2010/04/call-widget-with-shortcode/

Problem solved!